# How to add a file to MonoDevelop Packaging project

Tags: msbuild, mono, monodevelop

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

I'd like to add a **ReadMe.txt** file to the zipped binary archive in my MonoDevelop Packaging project.

I tried this:

```
    <Package name="Linux Binaries">
      <Builder targetFile="..\script-keeper-bin-linux.zip" platform="Linux" configuration="Release" ctype="BinariesZipPackageBuilder">
        <ChildEntries>
          <SolutionItemReference path="..\Keeper.OfScripts\Keeper.OfScripts.csproj" />

          <!-- ************************************** -->
          <!-- This is where I tried to add the file. -->
          <SolutionItemReference path="..\Keeper.OfScripts\ReadMe.txt" />

        </ChildEntries>
        <ExcludedFiles>
          <File>Keeper.OfScripts,ProgramFiles,System.Web.Mvc.dll</File>
        </ExcludedFiles>
        <RootEntry path="..\Keeper.OfScripts.sln" id=":root:" />
      </Builder>
    </Package>
```

But nothing got added (the package did build correctly, but it omitted the **ReadMe.txt** file).

Is this is same syntax as an MSBuild file? Either way, I can't find anything that helps.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Well, I *thought* I set the build-action to *Content* and properties to *Copy to Output Directory* for **ReadMe.txt**, but I didn't. If you set those things, then the file will be included in your package.

Doing so also checks the *Include in deploy* box in the file's property window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way packaging projects work is somewhat strange. The format is not currently compatible with MSBuild, despite the file header. Essentially, a packaging project only includes *projects* - the list of included projects can be edited in the package options. The files that are included from each project are controlled using the property grid when the files are selected in the solution tree. When the packaging project is built, it can generate several different kinds of package, but they all have the same sources.

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction. I'll update my question with what I found.